# powershell verify my array elements type

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, int, element

Sorry for being noob, but I'm trying to understand arrays in powershell.
So I have:

```
$a = @("just", "a", "test")
$b = @(1,2,3)
```

No explicit type casting declared.
Is it true that $a array has string elements, and $b has int elements? If so, is there any command to verify and show array elements type? Thanks!

**Edited:**

```
PS> $a | get-member

   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB)
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
CopyTo           Method                System.Void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex,...
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringCompari...
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string...
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()
GetType          Method                type GetType()
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode()
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), i...
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normaliz...
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startI...
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizat...
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char padding...
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, s...
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringCom...
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}
Length           Property              System.Int32 Length {get;}
```

As you can see, the get-member doesn't return me string, as expected, but alot of info from which I don't understand anything.

Comment: `$a[0].GetType()`

Comment: Are you asking purely for curiosity's sake or solving some problem? As Shawn Esterman points out you can get the type of any object (including an object in an array) by calling its `GetType()` method.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I will convert them later, and I want to be sure it has converted them indeed to another type, like from string to int...just want to verify everything works as expected.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.GetType()` method to verify what Type an object has:

```
[PS] $a.GetType().Fullname
[PS] $b.GetType().Fullname
```

You will see that both appear to be:

```
System.Object[]
```

Where the `[]` brackets indicate an array of the `System.Object` type.

If you use the `Get-Member` cmdlet you will see what type the data is within the array:

```
[PS] $a | Get-Member
[PS] $b | Get-Member
```

You will see the following at the top of the response:

```
TypeName: System.String
...

TypeName: System.Int32
....
```

If you have an array with different types, you'll see each type returned.

You *can* specify what type an array will hold, for example the following array looks like it would hold integers, but actually they are strings:

```
[PS] $c = [System.String[]]@(1,2,3)

[PS] $c.GetType().Fullname
System.String[]
```

**A bit more on `Get-Member`...**

As we saw above, arrays are often (by default) objects of type `[System.Object[]]`: these are fairly generic collections which could contain both strings and integers in the array. For example:

```
$d = @("One",2,3.0)  # String, Int32, Double

$d | Get-Member
```

When you pipe the object **$c** into the `Get-Member` cmdlet, it processes the *members* of the array and determines their type, hence the second command returns details of all three types.

The extra stuff that is returned by `Get-Member` tells you what can be done with each type, e.g. a String supports the `ToLower` method which is not supported for Int or Double types.

**A bit more on `GetType()`...**

In order to get the type for each member of the array, you can loop through them:

```
[PS] $d | ForEach-Object {$_.GetType().FullName}
System.String
System.Int32
System.Double
```

**Looking at the array object in more detail**

One thing you might want to experiment with is digging into the nature of the array in which you are holding your data with:

```
$d.PSObject
$d.PSObject.BaseObject
$d.PSObject.Members
$d.PSObject.Properties
```

Just remember that you are looking at the *array* not the data *within* the array, so the Members and Properties you find relate to the array, not the elements within the array.

Comment: I have added a bit more to get your started / to help you navigate the many web pages, blogs, etc. on this subject!